# unable to locate package ros-electric-brown-drivers

Tags: ubuntu-precise, ubuntu, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

$ sudo apt-get install ros-electric-brown-drivers
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-electric-brown-drivers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36126/unable-to-locate-package-ros-electric-brown-drivers/) by [allmin123](https://answers.ros.org/users/2580/allmin123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-06-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allmin123](https://answers.ros.org/users/2580/allmin123/) on 2012-06-09**:
can anyone suggest how to fix this??

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-06-10**:
What OS are you using? Do other ROS stacks install fine?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-06-10**:
According to the status page ( http://www.ros.org/debbuild/electric.html ), the brown drivers stack is building fine and should be available.

**Comment by [allmin123](https://answers.ros.org/users/2580/allmin123/) on 2012-06-13**:
I am using Ubuntu Precise..... I cannot install other ros stacks either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu Precise does not support ROS Electric (see [REP 3](http://answers.ros.org/question/30234/ubuntu-1204-beta-install-ros-desktop-full/))

You should first follow the general instructions for [installing ROS Fuerte](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation) before installing brown drivers. The brown drivers stack should be available on Fuerte (see [fuerte debbuild status](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/fuerte.html)).

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu

In the above link be sure to do step 1.2, 1.3 and

$ sudo apt-get update

then

$ sudo apt-get install ros-electric-brown-drivers

If that doesn't work follow the complete tutorial in the above link.

---

Originally posted by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) with karma: 600 on 2012-06-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2